# Replacement guide for different cleats?

Tags: road-bike, bike-fit, road, cleat

I'm planning to replace my wellgo 6 degree float to look keo grip 9 degree float. I've searched for cleats replacement guide online but most of them only caters to replacing identical cleats. I'm pretty sure these 2 cleats have some minor differences. How should I go about it? Or should I go to a bike fitter for cleats fitting again? The latter is probably my last resort as it will cost a lot just for cleats fitting.

Answer (score 1):

Wellgo make a variety of aftermarket replacement cleats and pedals for various systems, including Shimano's SPD and Look Keo.  They should be (almost) completely compatible with the equivalent system's branded cleats.  I've personally used Wellgo Keo-compatible cleats as a replacement for Look-branded cleats, and there were no issues at all.

Assuming you're talking about [these Wellgo 6-degree cleats](https://www.chainreactioncycles.com/wellgo-r096-cleats-look-keo-compatible-/rp-prod110505) then the [Keo equivalent 9-degree float](https://www.competitivecyclist.com/look-cycle-keo-grip-road-cleat) should be a drop-in replacement.

The way I change cleats is to take a Sharpie and trace around the base (the heel-facing end) of the old cleat before removing it, and then align the new cleat to that line when installing the new ones.  It shouldn't require a fitter, since the plastic is as identically shaped as they can make it.

(Just to be clear, trace along where the cleat meets the shoe, as indicated in this picture.  This shape is dictated by the shape of the pedal, and any compatible cleat must have this exact shape here.)

[image: Look Keo cleat with the alignment line to mark indicated on it]

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

I'm using https://www.chainreactioncycles.com/wellgo-r096-cleats-look-keo-compatible-/rp-prod110505

Not sure if it is the same since it doesn't say grip. Also, off topic, did you have to change up the look grip cleats often and if so, what is your walking habit?

Comment: Oops, wrong link.  That's the exact link I intended to have in my post, so yes, it's the same. :)  I'll fix.  I don't change my cleats often, but I always carry [cleat covers](https://www.competitivecyclist.com/look-cycle-keo-cleat-cover) in my pocket when riding and put them on every time I dismount.  They'll still get wear from stepping down at stops, but much less.  And if you're like me and you habitually step down on the same side, you can swap the cleats between sides when the one is about 75% worn.

Comment: My shoes are both black-soled so sharpie doesn't show up.  I use an old bottle of white-out fluid.  One could also use short pieces of tape temporarily.  If you're super-confident of your placement, then scratch the outline into your shoe so its permanent.